# Angular 7 correct way to check if JSON parse returns a specific object

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular7

I'm a little confused about this.
I have a server returning a JSON string that represents an array of custom objects that I have defined. I need to perform some tests and check if each element of this array can be correctly cast/parsed to my object.
What is the correct way to do this?
I thought about creating a new Object and passing my `JSON.parse(element)` result to the constructor, but then how do I check if it was correctly created? Does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple way to check it:

```
checkJsonObject(string) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(string);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: But how do I check if the parsing returns a specific type of object, in this case my custom object? This only checks if the string passed is a correct json string...

Comment: You can use the `typeof` operator of javascript. Might it will help. 
example if var a contains the JSON object. Then you can write it in conditional statement as `if(typeof a == 'object')`. These will return you true of false value.

Comment: Yes with typeof it tells me it's an object, not if it's a particular custom Object